# How do I plot a scatterplot with this kind of dataset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am a complete beginner of Javascript and D3. Currently I have been trying to create a scatterplot with x-axis showing the years and percentiles for every year and y-axis showing the values for 3 variables. But I cannot seem to get my code running. Please help.

This is the excerpt of the dataset I have now:

```
country_code,year,welfare_type,percentile,avg_welfare,pop_share,welfare_share
AUS,2014,income,1,2.706183088,0.009969853,4.13E-04
AUS,2014,income,2,11.03834646,0.010027236,0.001695224
AUS,2014,income,3,15.21296516,0.009923341,0.002312137
AUS,2014,income,4,17.78666642,0.009876024,0.00269041
AUS,2014,income,5,19.65899193,0.009817937,0.002956128
AUS,2014,income,6,21.23338101,0.010270198,0.003339948
AUS,2014,income,7,22.71642933,0.010107506,0.003516624
AUS,2014,income,8,23.88424149,0.010001223,0.003658528
AUS,2014,income,9,24.95633096,0.009820398,0.003753631
AUS,2014,income,10,25.78625374,0.010083031,0.003982182
AUS,2014,income,11,26.61719414,0.00994973,0.004056163
AUS,2014,income,12,27.43463276,0.010096198,0.004242275
AUS,2014,income,13,28.31720791,0.010045165,0.004356616
AUS,2014,income,14,29.23106771,0.009896533,0.004430671
AUS,2014,income,16,30.55067193,0.009863549,0.004615256
AUS,2014,income,15,29.89843511,0.010094814,0.004622624
AUS,2014,income,17,31.20316268,0.010020247,0.004788713
AUS,2014,income,19,32.38771182,0.009888694,0.004905248
AUS,2014,income,18,31.82871304,0.010124787,0.004935677
AUS,2014,income,20,32.95847038,0.00998462,0.005040114
AUS,2014,income,21,33.6474718,0.010047902,0.00517809
AUS,2014,income,22,34.33875307,0.010052882,0.005287092
AUS,2014,income,23,35.01464846,0.0099175,0.005318556
AUS,2014,income,24,35.63748207,0.010094145,0.005509578
AUS,2014,income,26,37.03581494,0.009755934,0.005533916
AUS,2014,income,25,36.26642742,0.009996408,0.005552525
AUS,2014,income,28,38.23585461,0.009992649,0.00585185
AUS,2014,income,29,38.94099912,0.009912763,0.005912125
AUS,2014,income,27,37.61468566,0.010266587,0.005914599
AUS,2014,income,30,39.66490264,0.010092823,0.006131417
AUS,2014,income,31,40.37644593,0.009921456,0.006135434
AUS,2014,income,32,41.02135057,0.00998833,0.006275446
AUS,2014,income,34,42.01105027,0.009758772,0.006279145
AUS,2014,income,33,41.62407432,0.010037465,0.006398975
AUS,2014,income,36,43.03352375,0.010044596,0.006620354
AUS,2014,income,37,43.59007717,0.009950045,0.00664285
AUS,2014,income,35,42.4723306,0.010237364,0.006659414
AUS,2014,income,38,44.05401838,0.009974684,0.006730177
AUS,2014,income,39,44.59078719,0.010080713,0.006884592
AUS,2014,income,40,45.22011959,0.010009614,0.006932515
AUS,2014,income,41,45.78335857,0.009937155,0.006968054
AUS,2014,income,42,46.49121536,0.010059652,0.007163011
AUS,2014,income,44,47.72893726,0.009855791,0.007204686
AUS,2014,income,43,47.10222632,0.010004851,0.007217617
AUS,2014,income,46,48.96673209,0.009786594,0.007339635
AUS,2014,income,45,48.31298287,0.010139416,0.007502717
AUS,2014,income,47,49.62708527,0.010060983,0.007647174
AUS,2014,income,49,51.09694646,0.009849214,0.00770794
AUS,2014,income,48,50.38862979,0.010149339,0.007832711
AUS,2014,income,50,51.83564211,0.010094099,0.008013788
AUS,2014,income,51,52.57598103,0.01003079,0.008077265
AUS,2014,income,52,53.44639201,0.010033813,0.00821346
AUS,2014,income,53,54.36172111,0.009865484,0.008213976
AUS,2014,income,54,55.3113642,0.01011584,0.008569552
AUS,2014,income,55,56.25654416,0.009960817,0.008582421
AUS,2014,income,56,57.0291785,0.009991576,0.008727159
AUS,2014,income,57,57.94137541,0.009839134,0.008731472
AUS,2014,income,58,58.59715086,0.009916506,0.008899733
AUS,2014,income,60,60.15320318,0.010046913,0.00925621
AUS,2014,income,59,59.28244241,0.01025988,0.009315586
AUS,2014,income,61,61.24756855,0.009985114,0.009366636
AUS,2014,income,62,62.45605758,0.010001891,0.0095675
AUS,2014,income,63,63.53518536,0.010014243,0.009744829
AUS,2014,income,64,64.52243794,0.00991656,0.009799718
AUS,2014,income,66,66.6700305,0.009775673,0.009982036
AUS,2014,income,65,65.58589209,0.010078047,0.010123451
AUS,2014,income,68,68.73954583,0.010002134,0.010530309
AUS,2014,income,67,67.67139554,0.010204008,0.01057591
AUS,2014,income,69,69.68166938,0.009959784,0.010629437
AUS,2014,income,70,70.78054852,0.009890164,0.01072159
AUS,2014,income,72,73.10381941,0.009986389,0.011181249
AUS,2014,income,71,71.82035176,0.010175222,0.011192657
AUS,2014,income,73,74.50528527,0.010016861,0.011430376
AUS,2014,income,74,75.81199845,0.009955876,0.011560037
AUS,2014,income,75,77.04250182,0.010042825,0.011850264
AUS,2014,income,76,78.565506,0.009955459,0.011979398
AUS,2014,income,77,80.40478014,0.009977753,0.012287298
AUS,2014,income,78,82.12333785,0.010043796,0.012632993
AUS,2014,income,79,83.79248925,0.009988891,0.012819295
AUS,2014,income,80,85.55768023,0.009991496,0.013092763
AUS,2014,income,81,87.47915,0.010038706,0.013450056
AUS,2014,income,82,89.38254022,0.009986228,0.013670864
AUS,2014,income,83,91.63481485,0.009953002,0.013968713
AUS,2014,income,84,93.91744067,0.010000544,0.01438506
AUS,2014,income,85,96.41946083,0.01005068,0.014842324
AUS,2014,income,86,99.54540544,0.009921946,0.015127246
AUS,2014,income,87,102.9654549,0.010061255,0.015866659
AUS,2014,income,88,105.971401,0.010025493,0.016271822
AUS,2014,income,89,109.1419537,0.009901563,0.016551497
AUS,2014,income,90,112.514213,0.009965222,0.017172604
AUS,2014,income,91,116.3289357,0.010076984,0.017953955
AUS,2014,income,92,120.6459775,0.01006046,0.018589704
AUS,2014,income,93,125.5685177,0.009956968,0.019149158
AUS,2014,income,94,131.9060045,0.010046029,0.020295548
AUS,2014,income,95,139.9451658,0.009996381,0.021426068
AUS,2014,income,96,148.6943539,0.009975502,0.022718048
AUS,2014,income,97,161.3097917,0.009998721,0.024702846
AUS,2014,income,98,181.7236599,0.010022054,0.027893949
AUS,2014,income,99,217.7250904,0.009993702,0.033325498
AUS,2014,income,100,419.3771126,0.010014813,0.064326418
AUS,2016,income,1,2.921344881,0.009891044,4.53E-04
AUS,2016,income,2,10.86946963,0.009887197,0.001684881
AUS,2016,income,3,14.96556705,0.010220573,0.002398038
AUS,2016,income,4,17.41174479,0.009960163,0.00271892
AUS,2016,income,5,18.84613732,0.009949316,0.002939701
AUS,2016,income,6,20.38088749,0.010060453,0.00321461
AUS,2016,income,7,21.94488945,0.009988179,0.003436429
AUS,2016,income,8,22.9706105,0.010022147,0.003609283
AUS,2016,income,10,25.00293992,0.009354153,0.003666766
AUS,2016,income,9,24.0096397,0.009995351,0.003762455
AUS,2016,income,12,26.62725434,0.009971033,0.004162499
AUS,2016,income,13,27.3528324,0.010032514,0.00430229
AUS,2016,income,11,25.76408298,0.010652475,0.004302817
AUS,2016,income,14,28.17373116,0.009973422,0.004405307
AUS,2016,income,15,29.05679359,0.00986932,0.004495961
AUS,2016,income,16,29.93744756,0.010155514,0.004766551
AUS,2016,income,17,30.59293397,0.010010156,0.004801197
AUS,2016,income,18,31.20220578,0.010001867,0.004892761
AUS,2016,income,19,31.63021913,0.009993163,0.00495556
AUS,2016,income,20,32.32867948,0.010001634,0.005069283
AUS,2016,income,21,33.06058859,0.01000566,0.005186136
AUS,2016,income,22,33.67194926,0.009929743,0.005241962
AUS,2016,income,23,34.30940692,0.010074751,0.005419199
AUS,2016,income,24,34.84748724,0.009926655,0.005423279
AUS,2016,income,25,35.29368138,0.009943476,0.005502028
AUS,2016,income,27,36.74800232,0.009728971,0.005605163
AUS,2016,income,26,35.97401424,0.010091598,0.005691627
AUS,2016,income,29,38.19577669,0.009894985,0.005925406
AUS,2016,income,28,37.45386648,0.010306717,0.006052079
AUS,2016,income,30,38.83223624,0.010107443,0.006153488
AUS,2016,income,31,39.40745425,0.009980666,0.006166312
AUS,2016,income,32,40.10945618,0.009983972,0.006278238
AUS,2016,income,33,40.78564161,0.00995818,0.006367587
AUS,2016,income,35,41.63865286,0.009996976,0.006526088
AUS,2016,income,34,41.39825541,0.010074415,0.006538671
AUS,2016,income,36,42.02093891,0.009971631,0.006569307
AUS,2016,income,37,42.62393647,0.010025866,0.006699819
AUS,2016,income,38,43.26897405,0.009984334,0.006773034
AUS,2016,income,39,43.95228489,0.009974039,0.006872902
AUS,2016,income,40,44.61490953,0.010040435,0.007022959
AUS,2016,income,41,45.37646989,0.009964403,0.007088749
AUS,2016,income,42,45.97395005,0.010033745,0.007232068
AUS,2016,income,43,46.65105029,0.009968655,0.007290975
AUS,2016,income,46,48.73932332,0.009553738,0.007300295
AUS,2016,income,44,47.42866471,0.010030614,0.007458578
AUS,2016,income,45,48.02211222,0.009979524,0.007513438
AUS,2016,income,48,50.01934665,0.009986286,0.007831224
AUS,2016,income,49,50.72917496,0.010008305,0.007959869
AUS,2016,income,50,51.46537181,0.010003591,0.008071582
AUS,2016,income,47,49.36311865,0.010466048,0.008099774
AUS,2016,income,51,52.29708356,0.009965039,0.008170414
AUS,2016,income,52,53.21992628,0.009944834,0.008297732
AUS,2016,income,53,53.94076603,0.010028668,0.008481017
AUS,2016,income,54,54.73058001,0.010073508,0.008643675
AUS,2016,income,55,55.66432548,0.009998435,0.008725626
AUS,2016,income,56,56.71593196,0.009997721,0.008889835
AUS,2016,income,58,58.50555862,0.009824501,0.009011461
AUS,2016,income,57,57.57195448,0.009994539,0.009021138
AUS,2016,income,59,59.45792769,0.010138709,0.009451049
AUS,2016,income,60,60.62677419,0.01000758,0.009512204
AUS,2016,income,61,61.80787097,0.00992854,0.009620924
AUS,2016,income,63,63.43629548,0.009874096,0.009820255
AUS,2016,income,62,62.54525396,0.010092093,0.009896081
AUS,2016,income,64,64.60173999,0.010140293,0.010270281
AUS,2016,income,65,65.60493276,0.009991716,0.010276948
AUS,2016,income,66,66.72095274,0.0100073,0.010468074
AUS,2016,income,67,67.93312637,0.009973639,0.010622405
AUS,2016,income,68,69.29769991,0.009953586,0.010813991
AUS,2016,income,69,70.61850675,0.010067056,0.011145732
AUS,2016,income,70,71.88259924,0.010003244,0.01127333
AUS,2016,income,71,73.1759581,0.009903166,0.011361353
AUS,2016,income,73,75.68829689,0.009855145,0.011694438
AUS,2016,income,72,74.49065685,0.010101602,0.01179722
AUS,2016,income,74,76.93036571,0.009955659,0.012007578
AUS,2016,income,77,81.22701085,0.009611704,0.012240199
AUS,2016,income,75,78.2816762,0.010156349,0.012464801
AUS,2016,income,76,79.70407585,0.01002164,0.012522958
AUS,2016,income,79,84.38656413,0.009776858,0.012934814
AUS,2016,income,78,82.90435259,0.010162592,0.013208984
AUS,2016,income,81,88.14204825,0.009881302,0.013654787
AUS,2016,income,80,85.99034668,0.010424978,0.014054405
AUS,2016,income,82,89.83042069,0.010017994,0.014108856
AUS,2016,income,83,91.3544176,0.010030154,0.014365632
AUS,2016,income,84,93.16756247,0.010100337,0.014753267
AUS,2016,income,85,95.15888443,0.009933997,0.014820436
AUS,2016,income,86,97.77003411,0.010059915,0.015420118
AUS,2016,income,87,100.7484106,0.009970617,0.015748813
AUS,2016,income,88,103.3231109,0.010040767,0.016264921
AUS,2016,income,89,106.4835939,0.009997772,0.016690661
AUS,2016,income,90,109.9008807,0.009943091,0.017132083
AUS,2016,income,91,113.327115,0.01006132,0.01787625
AUS,2016,income,92,117.2869678,0.009933027,0.01826497
AUS,2016,income,93,121.4394061,0.009984393,0.019009422
AUS,2016,income,94,126.5037933,0.010056994,0.019946163
AUS,2016,income,95,133.7253411,0.010013734,0.020994106
AUS,2016,income,96,142.5918642,0.009978695,0.022307768
AUS,2016,income,97,153.5144822,0.009931858,0.023903829
AUS,2016,income,98,170.2017432,0.010084885,0.026910549
AUS,2016,income,99,208.2369816,0.010000861,0.032649976
AUS,2016,income,100,360.2167398,0.010018403,0.056578312
AUS,2018,income,1,2.595366313,0.009842698,3.95E-04
AUS,2018,income,2,9.823911429,0.010133857,0.001540855
AUS,2018,income,3,14.02903825,0.010019847,0.002175663
AUS,2018,income,4,16.20475069,0.00999557,0.00250699
AUS,2018,income,5,18.10915852,0.00998426,0.002798445
AUS,2018,income,6,19.9508763,0.00993849,0.003068916
AUS,2018,income,7,21.28037443,0.009700865,0.003195158
AUS,2018,income,8,22.46745331,0.010256684,0.003566674
AUS,2018,income,9,23.58626711,0.010043957,0.003666627
AUS,2018,income,10,24.56020059,0.009778468,0.00371711
AUS,2018,income,11,25.42979959,0.010202929,0.004015785
AUS,2018,income,12,26.33331407,0.010042599,0.004093118
AUS,2018,income,13,27.40014618,0.010006882,0.004243794
AUS,2018,income,14,28.52270694,0.009951873,0.004393375
AUS,2018,income,15,29.52728239,0.010003639,0.004571767
AUS,2018,income,16,30.26886102,0.009941065,0.004657272
AUS,2018,income,17,31.05298971,0.010123957,0.004865824
AUS,2018,income,18,31.98053166,0.010029435,0.004964377
AUS,2018,income,20,33.22802717,0.009797099,0.00503854
AUS,2018,income,19,32.66549084,0.009992269,0.005051914
AUS,2018,income,21,33.63693313,0.010003789,0.005208151
AUS,2018,income,25,36.01406074,0.009539114,0.005317198
AUS,2018,income,22,34.17025041,0.010130968,0.005357988
AUS,2018,income,23,34.82676969,0.010063973,0.00542482
AUS,2018,income,24,35.36869964,0.010013115,0.005481393
AUS,2018,income,27,37.20731631,0.009821302,0.005655879
AUS,2018,income,33,40.87633985,0.009210976,0.005827474
AUS,2018,income,26,36.50531459,0.01045545,0.005907469
AUS,2018,income,28,37.85771532,0.010182103,0.005966155
AUS,2018,income,29,38.61389827,0.010002608,0.00597805
AUS,2018,income,30,39.23941491,0.009962674,0.006050637
AUS,2018,income,31,39.93717676,0.010022552,0.006195243
AUS,2018,income,32,40.47103984,0.009980693,0.006251838
AUS,2018,income,36,42.40615011,0.009803519,0.006434481
AUS,2018,income,35,41.79732628,0.010157682,0.006571216
AUS,2018,income,39,44.29336043,0.009680314,0.006636372
AUS,2018,income,38,43.63415757,0.010038815,0.006779719
AUS,2018,income,37,43.06505422,0.010175109,0.00678214
AUS,2018,income,34,41.19537868,0.010642366,0.006785617
AUS,2018,income,41,45.31986066,0.009964569,0.006989558
AUS,2018,income,40,44.78770392,0.010220832,0.007085128
AUS,2018,income,42,45.98918996,0.010131453,0.007211575
AUS,2018,income,43,46.75184156,0.009979741,0.007221388
AUS,2018,income,44,47.49359156,0.009980116,0.007336236
AUS,2018,income,45,48.33259569,0.010048654,0.007517106
AUS,2018,income,46,49.07601632,0.009919118,0.007534337
AUS,2018,income,47,49.90985642,0.0100312,0.007748932
AUS,2018,income,48,50.82979576,0.010008184,0.007873654
AUS,2018,income,49,51.65939593,0.009968356,0.007970316
AUS,2018,income,50,52.49251803,0.009898442,0.008042053
AUS,2018,income,52,53.87597193,0.0099824,0.008324013
AUS,2018,income,51,53.27500401,0.010125596,0.008349236
AUS,2018,income,53,54.62220616,0.009877231,0.008350397
AUS,2018,income,54,55.47221646,0.009776907,0.008394207
AUS,2018,income,55,56.23253556,0.010238282,0.008910815
AUS,2018,income,56,57.24371642,0.010085894,0.008936035
AUS,2018,income,58,59.10520774,0.009834502,0.008996649
AUS,2018,income,57,58.16688376,0.010051726,0.009049385
AUS,2018,income,60,60.91533476,0.009875512,0.009310841
AUS,2018,income,59,59.90437715,0.010183559,0.009441931
AUS,2018,income,61,61.75432927,0.009958307,0.009518217
AUS,2018,income,62,62.61595691,0.010139702,0.009826817
AUS,2018,income,63,63.64261438,0.010040373,0.009890097
AUS,2018,income,64,64.68995889,0.00999147,0.01000389
AUS,2018,income,65,65.87401702,0.009953768,0.010148557
AUS,2018,income,68,68.91650916,0.009713594,0.0103611
AUS,2018,income,66,66.8617044,0.01005883,0.010409445
AUS,2018,income,67,67.79991077,0.009982134,0.010475027
AUS,2018,income,70,70.96026521,0.009908804,0.010882762
AUS,2018,income,69,70.000275,0.010239873,0.011094225
AUS,2018,income,71,72.26105558,0.010004988,0.011189831
AUS,2018,income,72,73.60416061,0.010107856,0.011515003
AUS,2018,income,73,74.84108522,0.010028489,0.011616578
AUS,2018,income,74,76.30553539,0.009972862,0.011778189
AUS,2018,income,75,77.63277599,0.009953914,0.011960288
AUS,2018,income,76,78.97379055,0.010069723,0.012308445
AUS,2018,income,77,80.61337965,0.00997618,0.012447268
AUS,2018,income,78,82.35020384,0.010030576,0.012784779
AUS,2018,income,79,83.8521037,0.009943725,0.012905229
AUS,2018,income,80,85.3092945,0.010001952,0.013206379
AUS,2018,income,81,86.82983593,0.009983915,0.013417528
AUS,2018,income,82,88.95395683,0.009973547,0.013731487
AUS,2018,income,83,90.96324283,0.009967333,0.014032905
AUS,2018,income,84,93.16888148,0.010097804,0.01456131
```

I want the year and percentile attributes on the x-axis and divide the y-axis into three sections: avg_welfare, welfare_share and pop_share.

This is the current code I have, but nothing is showing on my browser. What is wrong with the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="1000"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js" charset="utf-8">

var margin = {top:100, right:80, bottom:80, left:80};

//Setting attributes of SVG
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")

//Setting attribute width and height as numbers instead of strings
var width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
var height = parseInt(svg.attr("height"));

svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
svg.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

//Setting attributes of x-axis
var xaxis = d3.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
              .scaleBand()

//Setting attributes of y-axis
var yaxis = d3.append("g")
              .scaleLinear()

//Extracting data
d3.csv("data/programmingassignment1data.csv", function(error, data){
   if (error) throw error;

   data.forEach(function(d){
      d.year = +d.year
      d.percentile = +d.percentile
      d.avg_welfare = +d.avg_welfare
      d.pop_share = +d.pop_share
      d.welfare_share = +d.welfare_share
      })

//Drawing x-axis
var x1 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.year}))
              .range([margin.left, width]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x1))

var x2 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.percentile}))
              .range([margin.left, width/5]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x2))

var x3 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.percentile}))
              .range([width/5, width*2/5]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x3))

var x4 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.percentile}))
              .range([width*2/5, width*3/5]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x4))
               
var x5 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.percentile}))
              .range([width*3/5, width*4/5]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x5))

var x6 = xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.percentile}))
              .range([width*4/5, width]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x6))

//Drawing y-axis
var y1 = yaxis.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.avg_welfare}), 0])
              .range([height, height/3]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y1))

var y2 = yaxis.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.welfare_share}), 0])
              .range([height/3, height*2/3]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y2))

var y3 = yaxis.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.pop_share}), 0])
              .range([height*2/3, 0]).padding(0.4)
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y3))

//Setting scatterplot attributes
var g = svg.append("g")
           .selectAll("dot")
           .data(data)
           .enter()    
           .append("circle")     

//Plotting scatterplots
var g1 = g.attr("cx", function(d) {return x1(d.year); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return y1(d.avg_welfare); })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", "green")

var g2 = g.attr("cx", function(d) {return x1(d.year); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return y2(d.welfare_share); })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", "blue")

var g3 = g.attr("cx", function(d) {return x1(d.year); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return y3(d.pop_share); })
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", "yellow")

//Adding chart title
svg.append("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(300,0)")
.attr("x", 50)
.attr("y", 50)
.attr("font-size", "40px")
.text("Distribution of wealth from 2014-2018");

//Adding data and axis labels
var gxLabels = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.top + 40) + ")")
                  .append("text")
                  .attr("y", 20)
                  .attr("x", margin.left + width/2)
                  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                  .attr("stroke", "black")
                  .text("Year");

var gyLabels = svg.append("g")
                  .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 30)
                  .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                  .attr("stroke", "black");

gyLabels.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 0 * height / 3) + ')')
        .text("Average Wealth");

gyLabels.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 1 * height / 3) + ')')
        .text("Share of Wealth");

gyLabels.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 2 * height / 3) + ')')
        .text("Population Share")

});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version that produces a stacked scatter plot.

The plot has two different x scales:

1. `xScaleYears`: Band scale for the three distinct years: `[2014, 2016, 2018]`. Ranges the entire width of the plot.
2. `xScalePercentile`: Band scale for the percentiles (`[1, 2...100]`). Ranges **1/3** of the width of the plot.

The sum of both scales returns the x coordinate for a given year and percentile:

`x_2014_40 = xScaleYears(2014) + xScalePercentile(40)`

[image]

**Drawing the Axes**

Event thought there is just *one* scale, there are *three* percentile axes - one for each year.

Each axis is transformed horizontally into the correct year band.
Each axis only shows ticks for every 10th year.

The below snipped produces this plot:
[image]

```js
// the data
  var dataCSVString = 'year,percentile,avg_welfare,pop_share,welfare_share\n' +
    '2014,1,2.706183088,0.009969853,4.13E-04\n' +
    '2014,2,11.03834646,0.010027236,0.001695224\n' +
    '2014,3,15.21296516,0.009923341,0.002312137\n' +
    '2014,4,17.78666642,0.009876024,0.00269041\n' +
    '2014,5,19.65899193,0.009817937,0.002956128\n' +
    '2014,6,21.23338101,0.010270198,0.003339948\n' +
    '2014,7,22.71642933,0.010107506,0.003516624\n' +
    '2014,8,23.88424149,0.010001223,0.003658528\n' +
    '2014,9,24.95633096,0.009820398,0.003753631\n' +
    '2014,10,25.78625374,0.010083031,0.003982182\n' +
    '2014,11,26.61719414,0.00994973,0.004056163\n' +
    '2014,12,27.43463276,0.010096198,0.004242275\n' +
    '2014,13,28.31720791,0.010045165,0.004356616\n' +
    '2014,14,29.23106771,0.009896533,0.004430671\n' +
    '2014,16,30.55067193,0.009863549,0.004615256\n' +
    '2014,15,29.89843511,0.010094814,0.004622624\n' +
    '2014,17,31.20316268,0.010020247,0.004788713\n' +
    '2014,19,32.38771182,0.009888694,0.004905248\n' +
    '2014,18,31.82871304,0.010124787,0.004935677\n' +
    '2014,20,32.95847038,0.00998462,0.005040114\n' +
    '2014,21,33.6474718,0.010047902,0.00517809\n' +
    '2014,22,34.33875307,0.010052882,0.005287092\n' +
    '2014,23,35.01464846,0.0099175,0.005318556\n' +
    '2014,24,35.63748207,0.010094145,0.005509578\n' +
    '2014,26,37.03581494,0.009755934,0.005533916\n' +
    '2014,25,36.26642742,0.009996408,0.005552525\n' +
    '2014,28,38.23585461,0.009992649,0.00585185\n' +
    '2014,29,38.94099912,0.009912763,0.005912125\n' +
    '2014,27,37.61468566,0.010266587,0.005914599\n' +
    '2014,30,39.66490264,0.010092823,0.006131417\n' +
    '2014,31,40.37644593,0.009921456,0.006135434\n' +
    '2014,32,41.02135057,0.00998833,0.006275446\n' +
    '2014,34,42.01105027,0.009758772,0.006279145\n' +
    '2014,33,41.62407432,0.010037465,0.006398975\n' +
    '2014,36,43.03352375,0.010044596,0.006620354\n' +
    '2014,37,43.59007717,0.009950045,0.00664285\n' +
    '2014,35,42.4723306,0.010237364,0.006659414\n' +
    '2014,38,44.05401838,0.009974684,0.006730177\n' +
    '2014,39,44.59078719,0.010080713,0.006884592\n' +
    '2014,40,45.22011959,0.010009614,0.006932515\n' +
    '2014,41,45.78335857,0.009937155,0.006968054\n' +
    '2014,42,46.49121536,0.010059652,0.007163011\n' +
    '2014,44,47.72893726,0.009855791,0.007204686\n' +
    '2014,43,47.10222632,0.010004851,0.007217617\n' +
    '2014,46,48.96673209,0.009786594,0.007339635\n' +
    '2014,45,48.31298287,0.010139416,0.007502717\n' +
    '2014,47,49.62708527,0.010060983,0.007647174\n' +
    '2014,49,51.09694646,0.009849214,0.00770794\n' +
    '2014,48,50.38862979,0.010149339,0.007832711\n' +
    '2014,50,51.83564211,0.010094099,0.008013788\n' +
    '2014,51,52.57598103,0.01003079,0.008077265\n' +
    '2014,52,53.44639201,0.010033813,0.00821346\n' +
    '2014,53,54.36172111,0.009865484,0.008213976\n' +
    '2014,54,55.3113642,0.01011584,0.008569552\n' +
    '2014,55,56.25654416,0.009960817,0.008582421\n' +
    '2014,56,57.0291785,0.009991576,0.008727159\n' +
    '2014,57,57.94137541,0.009839134,0.008731472\n' +
    '2014,58,58.59715086,0.009916506,0.008899733\n' +
    '2014,60,60.15320318,0.010046913,0.00925621\n' +
    '2014,59,59.28244241,0.01025988,0.009315586\n' +
    '2014,61,61.24756855,0.009985114,0.009366636\n' +
    '2014,62,62.45605758,0.010001891,0.0095675\n' +
    '2014,63,63.53518536,0.010014243,0.009744829\n' +
    '2014,64,64.52243794,0.00991656,0.009799718\n' +
    '2014,66,66.6700305,0.009775673,0.009982036\n' +
    '2014,65,65.58589209,0.010078047,0.010123451\n' +
    '2014,68,68.73954583,0.010002134,0.010530309\n' +
    '2014,67,67.67139554,0.010204008,0.01057591\n' +
    '2014,69,69.68166938,0.009959784,0.010629437\n' +
    '2014,70,70.78054852,0.009890164,0.01072159\n' +
    '2014,72,73.10381941,0.009986389,0.011181249\n' +
    '2014,71,71.82035176,0.010175222,0.011192657\n' +
    '2014,73,74.50528527,0.010016861,0.011430376\n' +
    '2014,74,75.81199845,0.009955876,0.011560037\n' +
    '2014,75,77.04250182,0.010042825,0.011850264\n' +
    '2014,76,78.565506,0.009955459,0.011979398\n' +
    '2014,77,80.40478014,0.009977753,0.012287298\n' +
    '2014,78,82.12333785,0.010043796,0.012632993\n' +
    '2014,79,83.79248925,0.009988891,0.012819295\n' +
    '2014,80,85.55768023,0.009991496,0.013092763\n' +
    '2014,81,87.47915,0.010038706,0.013450056\n' +
    '2014,82,89.38254022,0.009986228,0.013670864\n' +
    '2014,83,91.63481485,0.009953002,0.013968713\n' +
    '2014,84,93.91744067,0.010000544,0.01438506\n' +
    '2014,85,96.41946083,0.01005068,0.014842324\n' +
    '2014,86,99.54540544,0.009921946,0.015127246\n' +
    '2014,87,102.9654549,0.010061255,0.015866659\n' +
    '2014,88,105.971401,0.010025493,0.016271822\n' +
    '2014,89,109.1419537,0.009901563,0.016551497\n' +
    '2014,90,112.514213,0.009965222,0.017172604\n' +
    '2014,91,116.3289357,0.010076984,0.017953955\n' +
    '2014,92,120.6459775,0.01006046,0.018589704\n' +
    '2014,93,125.5685177,0.009956968,0.019149158\n' +
    '2014,94,131.9060045,0.010046029,0.020295548\n' +
    '2014,95,139.9451658,0.009996381,0.021426068\n' +
    '2014,96,148.6943539,0.009975502,0.022718048\n' +
    '2014,97,161.3097917,0.009998721,0.024702846\n' +
    '2014,98,181.7236599,0.010022054,0.027893949\n' +
    '2014,99,217.7250904,0.009993702,0.033325498\n' +
    '2014,100,419.3771126,0.010014813,0.064326418\n' +
    '2016,1,2.921344881,0.009891044,4.53E-04\n' +
    '2016,2,10.86946963,0.009887197,0.001684881\n' +
    '2016,3,14.96556705,0.010220573,0.002398038\n' +
    '2016,4,17.41174479,0.009960163,0.00271892\n' +
    '2016,5,18.84613732,0.009949316,0.002939701\n' +
    '2016,6,20.38088749,0.010060453,0.00321461\n' +
    '2016,7,21.94488945,0.009988179,0.003436429\n' +
    '2016,8,22.9706105,0.010022147,0.003609283\n' +
    '2016,10,25.00293992,0.009354153,0.003666766\n' +
    '2016,9,24.0096397,0.009995351,0.003762455\n' +
    '2016,12,26.62725434,0.009971033,0.004162499\n' +
    '2016,13,27.3528324,0.010032514,0.00430229\n' +
    '2016,11,25.76408298,0.010652475,0.004302817\n' +
    '2016,14,28.17373116,0.009973422,0.004405307\n' +
    '2016,15,29.05679359,0.00986932,0.004495961\n' +
    '2016,16,29.93744756,0.010155514,0.004766551\n' +
    '2016,17,30.59293397,0.010010156,0.004801197\n' +
    '2016,18,31.20220578,0.010001867,0.004892761\n' +
    '2016,19,31.63021913,0.009993163,0.00495556\n' +
    '2016,20,32.32867948,0.010001634,0.005069283\n' +
    '2016,21,33.06058859,0.01000566,0.005186136\n' +
    '2016,22,33.67194926,0.009929743,0.005241962\n' +
    '2016,23,34.30940692,0.010074751,0.005419199\n' +
    '2016,24,34.84748724,0.009926655,0.005423279\n' +
    '2016,25,35.29368138,0.009943476,0.005502028\n' +
    '2016,27,36.74800232,0.009728971,0.005605163\n' +
    '2016,26,35.97401424,0.010091598,0.005691627\n' +
    '2016,29,38.19577669,0.009894985,0.005925406\n' +
    '2016,28,37.45386648,0.010306717,0.006052079\n' +
    '2016,30,38.83223624,0.010107443,0.006153488\n' +
    '2016,31,39.40745425,0.009980666,0.006166312\n' +
    '2016,32,40.10945618,0.009983972,0.006278238\n' +
    '2016,33,40.78564161,0.00995818,0.006367587\n' +
    '2016,35,41.63865286,0.009996976,0.006526088\n' +
    '2016,34,41.39825541,0.010074415,0.006538671\n' +
    '2016,36,42.02093891,0.009971631,0.006569307\n' +
    '2016,37,42.62393647,0.010025866,0.006699819\n' +
    '2016,38,43.26897405,0.009984334,0.006773034\n' +
    '2016,39,43.95228489,0.009974039,0.006872902\n' +
    '2016,40,44.61490953,0.010040435,0.007022959\n' +
    '2016,41,45.37646989,0.009964403,0.007088749\n' +
    '2016,42,45.97395005,0.010033745,0.007232068\n' +
    '2016,43,46.65105029,0.009968655,0.007290975\n' +
    '2016,46,48.73932332,0.009553738,0.007300295\n' +
    '2016,44,47.42866471,0.010030614,0.007458578\n' +
    '2016,45,48.02211222,0.009979524,0.007513438\n' +
    '2016,48,50.01934665,0.009986286,0.007831224\n' +
    '2016,49,50.72917496,0.010008305,0.007959869\n' +
    '2016,50,51.46537181,0.010003591,0.008071582\n' +
    '2016,47,49.36311865,0.010466048,0.008099774\n' +
    '2016,51,52.29708356,0.009965039,0.008170414\n' +
    '2016,52,53.21992628,0.009944834,0.008297732\n' +
    '2016,53,53.94076603,0.010028668,0.008481017\n' +
    '2016,54,54.73058001,0.010073508,0.008643675\n' +
    '2016,55,55.66432548,0.009998435,0.008725626\n' +
    '2016,56,56.71593196,0.009997721,0.008889835\n' +
    '2016,58,58.50555862,0.009824501,0.009011461\n' +
    '2016,57,57.57195448,0.009994539,0.009021138\n' +
    '2016,59,59.45792769,0.010138709,0.009451049\n' +
    '2016,60,60.62677419,0.01000758,0.009512204\n' +
    '2016,61,61.80787097,0.00992854,0.009620924\n' +
    '2016,63,63.43629548,0.009874096,0.009820255\n' +
    '2016,62,62.54525396,0.010092093,0.009896081\n' +
    '2016,64,64.60173999,0.010140293,0.010270281\n' +
    '2016,65,65.60493276,0.009991716,0.010276948\n' +
    '2016,66,66.72095274,0.0100073,0.010468074\n' +
    '2016,67,67.93312637,0.009973639,0.010622405\n' +
    '2016,68,69.29769991,0.009953586,0.010813991\n' +
    '2016,69,70.61850675,0.010067056,0.011145732\n' +
    '2016,70,71.88259924,0.010003244,0.01127333\n' +
    '2016,71,73.1759581,0.009903166,0.011361353\n' +
    '2016,73,75.68829689,0.009855145,0.011694438\n' +
    '2016,72,74.49065685,0.010101602,0.01179722\n' +
    '2016,74,76.93036571,0.009955659,0.012007578\n' +
    '2016,77,81.22701085,0.009611704,0.012240199\n' +
    '2016,75,78.2816762,0.010156349,0.012464801\n' +
    '2016,76,79.70407585,0.01002164,0.012522958\n' +
    '2016,79,84.38656413,0.009776858,0.012934814\n' +
    '2016,78,82.90435259,0.010162592,0.013208984\n' +
    '2016,81,88.14204825,0.009881302,0.013654787\n' +
    '2016,80,85.99034668,0.010424978,0.014054405\n' +
    '2016,82,89.83042069,0.010017994,0.014108856\n' +
    '2016,83,91.3544176,0.010030154,0.014365632\n' +
    '2016,84,93.16756247,0.010100337,0.014753267\n' +
    '2016,85,95.15888443,0.009933997,0.014820436\n' +
    '2016,86,97.77003411,0.010059915,0.015420118\n' +
    '2016,87,100.7484106,0.009970617,0.015748813\n' +
    '2016,88,103.3231109,0.010040767,0.016264921\n' +
    '2016,89,106.4835939,0.009997772,0.016690661\n' +
    '2016,90,109.9008807,0.009943091,0.017132083\n' +
    '2016,91,113.327115,0.01006132,0.01787625\n' +
    '2016,92,117.2869678,0.009933027,0.01826497\n' +
    '2016,93,121.4394061,0.009984393,0.019009422\n' +
    '2016,94,126.5037933,0.010056994,0.019946163\n' +
    '2016,95,133.7253411,0.010013734,0.020994106\n' +
    '2016,96,142.5918642,0.009978695,0.022307768\n' +
    '2016,97,153.5144822,0.009931858,0.023903829\n' +
    '2016,98,170.2017432,0.010084885,0.026910549\n' +
    '2016,99,208.2369816,0.010000861,0.032649976\n' +
    '2016,100,360.2167398,0.010018403,0.056578312\n' +
    '2018,1,2.595366313,0.009842698,3.95E-04\n' +
    '2018,2,9.823911429,0.010133857,0.001540855\n' +
    '2018,3,14.02903825,0.010019847,0.002175663\n' +
    '2018,4,16.20475069,0.00999557,0.00250699\n' +
    '2018,5,18.10915852,0.00998426,0.002798445\n' +
    '2018,6,19.9508763,0.00993849,0.003068916\n' +
    '2018,7,21.28037443,0.009700865,0.003195158\n' +
    '2018,8,22.46745331,0.010256684,0.003566674\n' +
    '2018,9,23.58626711,0.010043957,0.003666627\n' +
    '2018,10,24.56020059,0.009778468,0.00371711\n' +
    '2018,11,25.42979959,0.010202929,0.004015785\n' +
    '2018,12,26.33331407,0.010042599,0.004093118\n' +
    '2018,13,27.40014618,0.010006882,0.004243794\n' +
    '2018,14,28.52270694,0.009951873,0.004393375\n' +
    '2018,15,29.52728239,0.010003639,0.004571767\n' +
    '2018,16,30.26886102,0.009941065,0.004657272\n' +
    '2018,17,31.05298971,0.010123957,0.004865824\n' +
    '2018,18,31.98053166,0.010029435,0.004964377\n' +
    '2018,20,33.22802717,0.009797099,0.00503854\n' +
    '2018,19,32.66549084,0.009992269,0.005051914\n' +
    '2018,21,33.63693313,0.010003789,0.005208151\n' +
    '2018,25,36.01406074,0.009539114,0.005317198\n' +
    '2018,22,34.17025041,0.010130968,0.005357988\n' +
    '2018,23,34.82676969,0.010063973,0.00542482\n' +
    '2018,24,35.36869964,0.010013115,0.005481393\n' +
    '2018,27,37.20731631,0.009821302,0.005655879\n' +
    '2018,33,40.87633985,0.009210976,0.005827474\n' +
    '2018,26,36.50531459,0.01045545,0.005907469\n' +
    '2018,28,37.85771532,0.010182103,0.005966155\n' +
    '2018,29,38.61389827,0.010002608,0.00597805\n' +
    '2018,30,39.23941491,0.009962674,0.006050637\n' +
    '2018,31,39.93717676,0.010022552,0.006195243\n' +
    '2018,32,40.47103984,0.009980693,0.006251838\n' +
    '2018,36,42.40615011,0.009803519,0.006434481\n' +
    '2018,35,41.79732628,0.010157682,0.006571216\n' +
    '2018,39,44.29336043,0.009680314,0.006636372\n' +
    '2018,38,43.63415757,0.010038815,0.006779719\n' +
    '2018,37,43.06505422,0.010175109,0.00678214\n' +
    '2018,34,41.19537868,0.010642366,0.006785617\n' +
    '2018,41,45.31986066,0.009964569,0.006989558\n' +
    '2018,40,44.78770392,0.010220832,0.007085128\n' +
    '2018,42,45.98918996,0.010131453,0.007211575\n' +
    '2018,43,46.75184156,0.009979741,0.007221388\n' +
    '2018,44,47.49359156,0.009980116,0.007336236\n' +
    '2018,45,48.33259569,0.010048654,0.007517106\n' +
    '2018,46,49.07601632,0.009919118,0.007534337\n' +
    '2018,47,49.90985642,0.0100312,0.007748932\n' +
    '2018,48,50.82979576,0.010008184,0.007873654\n' +
    '2018,49,51.65939593,0.009968356,0.007970316\n' +
    '2018,50,52.49251803,0.009898442,0.008042053\n' +
    '2018,52,53.87597193,0.0099824,0.008324013\n' +
    '2018,51,53.27500401,0.010125596,0.008349236\n' +
    '2018,53,54.62220616,0.009877231,0.008350397\n' +
    '2018,54,55.47221646,0.009776907,0.008394207\n' +
    '2018,55,56.23253556,0.010238282,0.008910815\n' +
    '2018,56,57.24371642,0.010085894,0.008936035\n' +
    '2018,58,59.10520774,0.009834502,0.008996649\n' +
    '2018,57,58.16688376,0.010051726,0.009049385\n' +
    '2018,60,60.91533476,0.009875512,0.009310841\n' +
    '2018,59,59.90437715,0.010183559,0.009441931\n' +
    '2018,61,61.75432927,0.009958307,0.009518217\n' +
    '2018,62,62.61595691,0.010139702,0.009826817\n' +
    '2018,63,63.64261438,0.010040373,0.009890097\n' +
    '2018,64,64.68995889,0.00999147,0.01000389\n' +
    '2018,65,65.87401702,0.009953768,0.010148557\n' +
    '2018,68,68.91650916,0.009713594,0.0103611\n' +
    '2018,66,66.8617044,0.01005883,0.010409445\n' +
    '2018,67,67.79991077,0.009982134,0.010475027\n' +
    '2018,70,70.96026521,0.009908804,0.010882762\n' +
    '2018,69,70.000275,0.010239873,0.011094225\n' +
    '2018,71,72.26105558,0.010004988,0.011189831\n' +
    '2018,72,73.60416061,0.010107856,0.011515003\n' +
    '2018,73,74.84108522,0.010028489,0.011616578\n' +
    '2018,74,76.30553539,0.009972862,0.011778189\n' +
    '2018,75,77.63277599,0.009953914,0.011960288\n' +
    '2018,76,78.97379055,0.010069723,0.012308445\n' +
    '2018,77,80.61337965,0.00997618,0.012447268\n' +
    '2018,78,82.35020384,0.010030576,0.012784779\n' +
    '2018,79,83.8521037,0.009943725,0.012905229\n' +
    '2018,80,85.3092945,0.010001952,0.013206379\n' +
    '2018,81,86.82983593,0.009983915,0.013417528\n' +
    '2018,82,88.95395683,0.009973547,0.013731487\n' +
    '2018,83,90.96324283,0.009967333,0.014032905\n' +
    '2018,84,93.16888148,0.010097804,0.01456131\n';

  var margin = {top: 100, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 80}

  var svg = d3.select("svg")

  var width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
  svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);

  var height = parseInt(svg.attr("height"));
  svg.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var g = svg.append("g")

  /** parse the data
   *
   * This produces the same as
   * @code
   * d3.csv(dataCSVString, function(error, data)
   * @endcode
   *
   * I just can't add external CSV resource files to the StackOverflow Code Snippet
   */
  var data = d3.csvParse(dataCSVString);
  
  // parse to number
  data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.year = +d.year
    d.percentile = +d.percentile
    d.avg_welfare = +d.avg_welfare
    d.pop_share = +d.pop_share
    d.welfare_share = +d.welfare_share
  });

/**
   * We will have two overloaded x-axes
   *  1. xAxisYears: A scale band for the different years: this is an array which contains the distinct years. For the given data: [2014, 2016, 2018]
   *  2. xAxisPercentile: For each year (2014, 2016, 2018) there will be a separate scale x-axis for the percentile
   */

    // the distinct years
  var years = [...new Set(data.map(function (d) {
      return d.year;
    }))];

  var xScaleYears = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(years)
    .range([margin.left, width])
    // no padding between the segments
    .padding(0.0);

  /*** three x scales for the precentiles of each year ***/

    // unique percentiles
  var percentiles = [...new Set(data.map(function (d) {
      return d.percentile;
    }))].sort(function (left, right) {
      return left - right;
    });

  // the width of one segment
  const xSegmentWidth = (width - margin.left) / 3;
  // the scale over one single year segment
  var xScalePercentile = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(percentiles)
    .range([0, xSegmentWidth]).padding(0.0);

  var yScaleAverageWelfare = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.avg_welfare
    })])
    .range([margin.top + 0 * height / 3, margin.top + 1 * height / 3]);

  var yScalePopulationShare = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.welfare_share
    })])
    .range([margin.top + 1 * height / 3, margin.top + 2 * height / 3]);

  var yScaleWelfareShare = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.pop_share
    })])
    .range([margin.top + 2 * height / 3, margin.top + 3 * height / 3]);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.top + 0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScaleYears));

  /** the x axis for the percentile scale with reduced ticks
   *
   * Too many ticks make it unreadable.
   */
  var percentileAxisTickValues = percentiles.filter(function (percentile) {
    return percentile % 10 == 0; // only every 10th tick
  });
  // the x-axis with selected tick values
  var percentileAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScalePercentile)
    .tickValues(percentileAxisTickValues);

  /** creates three groups - a group for each of the three percentile axes
   * We will transform each group horizontally to match the band of the coresponding year
   *
   */
  var groupWithPercentileAxes = g.append('g').attr('class', 'percentile-axes');

  groupWithPercentileAxes.selectAll('g.percentile-axis')
    .data(xScaleYears.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'percentile-axes')
    .attr('transform', function (year) {
      // get the starting x of the year band
      var yearStartX = xScaleYears(year);
      // the y coordinate at the bottom of the plot - plus some margin from the years
      var percentilAxisYPosition = height + margin.top + 20
      // transform into horizontal year segment and to the bottom
      return 'translate(' + yearStartX + ' ' + percentilAxisYPosition + ')';
    })
    // add th axis
    .call(percentileAxis);

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ' 0)')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScaleAverageWelfare))

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ' 0)')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScalePopulationShare))

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ' 0)')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScaleWelfareShare));

  // create a new group which includes the dots only
  var dotGroup = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'dot-group');

  dotGroup.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return xScaleYears(d.year) + xScalePercentile(d.percentile);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return yScaleAverageWelfare(d.avg_welfare);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "green")

  dotGroup.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return xScaleYears(d.year) + xScalePercentile(d.percentile);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return yScalePopulationShare(d.welfare_share);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "blue")

  dotGroup.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return xScaleYears(d.year) + xScalePercentile(d.percentile);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return yScaleWelfareShare(d.pop_share);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "yellow")

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(250,0)")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Distribution of wealth from 2014-2018");

  // append label for year
  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.top) + ")")
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("x", width + 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "beginning")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .text("Year");
  // append label for percentile
  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("x", width + 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "beginning")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .text("Percentile");

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 0 * height / 3) + ')')
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .text("Average Wealth");

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 1 * height / 3) + ')')
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .text("Share of Wealth");

  g.append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + (margin.top + 2 * height / 3) + ')')
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .text("Population Share");
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Christoph. Regarding the line of code for xAxis2, the reason xAxis2 has a different range is because I am trying to plot the percentile range of 0 to 100 for every year, not for the entire x-axis. So the x-axis contains 5 percentile ranges, each from 0 to 100, for all the years 2014 to 2018. So the output ideally wouldn't be a stacked scatterplot, but three scatterplots for each year on top of one another on the y-axis that have data points corresponding to each percentile for each year. I'm just not sure if .range(width(d.year)) is the right code for that.

Comment: Somehow my html file still won't run in any browser. I open up the html file and its a blank page. Do you need a CSS and JSON for the html script to run? What am I missing? Also I have edited the code to fewer lines (see edited original post), am I using the g element correctly?

Comment: Esther, sorry for the delay. I edited my answer to incorporate the percentile.I also moved everything into a code snipped so that you can run and verify the code. Please be aware that the CSV is coming from a local string as you cannot add resources to a Code Snipped.

Comment: Does this produces the result you were looking for?

Comment: Yes Christoph, that is it. Sorry I took so long to respond. I was busy with job searching and interviews the past few months. Appreciate your help!